# Replace Word Within Word - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, replace

I need to get a id from a html element and replace a part of the word. For example:

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="facebookCheckbox"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
var x = document.getElementById("facebookCheckbox");
var name = x.id;
name.replace("Checkbox","");
```

This obviously does not work because the replacing word has to be standalone for it to be replaced. Is there a different way of doing this?

I'm looking for purely javascript no jQuery

Thank you!

Comment: Strings are immutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> name.replace("Checkbox","");
> ```
>
> This obviously does not work because the replacing word has to be standalone for it to be replaced.

No, it does work and there's no need to be "standalone" - any part of the string can be matched. Only you did nothing with the [result of the operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
console.log(name.replace("Checkbox",""));
// or
name = name.replace("Checkbox","");
// or assign back to x.id maybe?
```

Comment: Wow, I can not believe that I missed that. I tried it out and looks like I had the syntax wrong! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a copy of string when replacing, so you must assign the result of `.replace()` back to `x.id`.

```
var x = document.getElementById("facebookCheckbox");
x.id = x.id.replace("Checkbox","");
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not going to work in this way. However you can have a marker kind of character by which you can break the name into array and implement the logic. For example:

```
var x = document.getElementById("facebook_Checkbox");
//Note I have added underscore in the Id
var name = x.id;
var arr=name.split("_");

//Now you have Checkbox and Facebook as string objects (part of array) and you can use them

name=arr[0]
```

I hope it will solve the purpose.